# failed to download file in angular 5

Tags: angular5

I am trying to download a pdf file from an url in angular 5.It works nicely in html by adding the url and 'download' property to 'a' tag.When I trying to do the same in angular 5,but it's not working.

**service.ts**

```
pdfDownload() {
         var options = new RequestOptions({responseType: ResponseContentType.Blob });

        // Process the file downloaded
        return this.http.get('https://.....test.pdf', options);
    }
```

**component.ts**

```
this.rcycCommonService.pdfDownload().subscribe((res)=>{
        this.saveFile(res.blob());
    })
saveFile (blobContent)  {
        var blob = new Blob([blobContent], { type: 'application/pdf' });
        saveAs(blob,"mypdf.pdf");
    };
```

but it shows following errors.

```
ERROR in src/app/rcyc-services/rcyc-common/rcyc-common.service.ts(426,137): error TS2345: Argument of type 'RequestOptions' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ headers?: HttpHeaders | { [header: string]: string | string[]; }; observe?: "body"; params?: Ht...'.
  Types of property 'headers' are incompatible.
    Type 'Headers' is not assignable to type 'HttpHeaders | { [header: string]: string | string[]; }'.
      Type 'Headers' is not assignable to type '{ [header: string]: string | string[]; }'.
        Index signature is missing in type 'Headers'.
```

can any one post the correct code to download a file in angular 5?

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: I still failed to create blob object  from the url

Answer (score 0):

this is a Typescript compilation error. As the error says, the second parameter of `this.http.get` should be a `Headers`, `HttpHeaders`, or string-indexed object (not a `RequestOptions`).

Comment: can you please post a working code in angular 5?I spend a lot of time in it

Comment: What IDE do you use? Are you getting syntax highlighting on the `http.get` call? You should see an error before you even try to run it.

Comment: ya i got syntax highlight in http.get

Comment: Does the syntax highlighting tell you why this won't compile? Take a look at the Angular documentation for what parameters `HttpClient.get` should be passed.

Answer (score 0):

you can use axios , its butter to download file

you can  install axios

> npm i axios

and import in your service

```
import axios from 'axios';

return axios.get(`${URL}`,{headers , responseType:"blob"}).then(({ data }) => {
      const downloadUrl = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([data]));
      const link = document.createElement('a');
      link.href = downloadUrl;
      link.setAttribute('download', `${fileName}.csv`); //any other extension and type you want
      document.body.appendChild(link);
      link.click();
      link.remove();
    });
```